# Invert RandomColor[] command

Tags: color

I want to know which plot corresponds to which color upon executing the command below.

```
      Show[Table[ListPlot[ Table[ RandomInteger[{1, 1000}],
      {j, 1, 50} ],PlotStyle -> RandomColor[] ], {l, 1, 10}] ]
```

In other words,  invert the  RandomColor[]   option.

Comment: with `plot = Show[...]`, define `pointsToColors = Association@
   Cases[plot, {___, Directive[___, c_?ColorQ], p_Point} :>  Rule[p[[1]], c], All]`?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks.

Comment: If the colors are just needed for a legend, use `ListPlot[RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, {10, 50}], PlotStyle -> Table[{RandomColor[], AbsolutePointSize[3]}, {10}], PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Automatic, LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}]]`